# Why isn't referentialIntegrity = "prisma" preventing foreign keys in migrations?

Tags: mysql, prisma, next-auth

I'm trying to set up nextAuth using prisma and PlanetScale. Planetscale does not allow foreign keys, however Prisma allows them to be disabled: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/referential-integrity

This issue is extensively discussed (https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/7292) and there's even an example that looks like it should work (https://templates.netlify.com/template/nextjs-planetscale-starter/).

I've set up my planetscale db and can connect to it. When I try to apply the NextAuth models, though, I get this error:

```
$ npx prisma migrate dev

...
    
Database error code: 1317

Database error:
Foreign keys cannot be created on this database. Learn more how to handle this: https://pris.ly/d/migrate-no-foreign-keys
```

Why is prisma trying to create foreign keys if I'm using the referentialIntegrety flag? what am I missing or misunderstanding here?

schema.prisma file:

```
datasource db {
  provider             = "mysql"
  url                  = env("DATABASE_URL")
  shadowDatabaseUrl    = env("SHADOW_DATABASE_URL")
  referentialIntegrity = "prisma"
}

generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["referentialIntegrity"]
}

model Account {
    id                       String   @id @default(cuid())
    createdAt                DateTime @default(now())
    updatedAt                DateTime @updatedAt
    userId                   String
    type                     String
    provider                 String
    providerAccountId        String
    refresh_token            String? @db.VarChar(500)
    access_token             String? @db.VarChar(500)
    refresh_token_expires_in Int?
    expires_at               Int?
    token_type               String?
    scope                    String?
    id_token                 String? @db.Text
    session_state            String?
    oauth_token_secret       String?
    oauth_token              String?

    user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

    @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
}

model Session {
    id           String   @id @default(cuid())
    sessionToken String   @unique
    expires      DateTime
    user         User?    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
    userId       String?
}

model User {
    id            String    @id @default(cuid())
    createdAt     DateTime  @default(now())
    updatedAt     DateTime  @updatedAt
    name          String?
    email         String?   @unique
    password      String?
    emailVerified DateTime?
    image         String?
    role          String?   @default("user")
    accounts      Account[]
    sessions      Session[]
}

model VerificationToken {
    identifier String
    token      String   @unique
    expires    DateTime

    @@unique([identifier, token])
}
```

```
$ npx prisma -v
Environment variables loaded from .env
prisma                  : 3.6.0
@prisma/client          : 3.6.0
Current platform        : darwin
Query Engine (Node-API) : libquery-engine dc520b92b1ebb2d28dc3161f9f82e875bd35d727 (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/libquery_engine-darwin.dylib.node)
Migration Engine        : migration-engine-cli dc520b92b1ebb2d28dc3161f9f82e875bd35d727 (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/migration-engine-darwin)
Introspection Engine    : introspection-core dc520b92b1ebb2d28dc3161f9f82e875bd35d727 (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/introspection-engine-darwin)
Format Binary           : prisma-fmt dc520b92b1ebb2d28dc3161f9f82e875bd35d727 (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/prisma-fmt-darwin)
Default Engines Hash    : dc520b92b1ebb2d28dc3161f9f82e875bd35d727
Studio                  : 0.440.0
Preview Features        : referentialIntegrity
```

Help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have copied your schema, and I have follow [this](https://docs.planetscale.com/tutorials/automatic-prisma-migrations) tutorial, and all works properly. In the image you can see that the migration works.

btw: my prisma version is 3.3.0

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had gone through those steps. My issue was a rookie mistake: I didn't realize the migration had already been created before I added those tags. All I needed to do was delete the migration and re-run migrate.

Answer (score 0):

I lost a few softer brained hours to this error.

After sleeping and looking at it for 5 minutes with fresh eyes I realized it was because the migration file had already been created from before I addedreferentialIntegrity = "prisma" and previewFeatures = ["referentialIntegrity"].

Lesson: prisma will not recognize differences in migrations caused by these kinds of config changes. You'll have to delete the effected migrations and recreate them.

Comment: I opened an issue in the Prisma repo to maybe handle this situation better: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/10843